Exclusive Or logical equivalences
On the Wikipedia page for Exclusive or, there are logical equivalences given which state:
\begin{align}
p\not\leftrightarrow q\equiv&(p\land\lnot q)\lor(\lnot p\land q)\\
\equiv&((p\land\lnot q) ∨ ¬p) \land ((p\land\lnot q) \lor q)
\end{align}
I was able to prove that these are equivalent with a truth table, but I'm trying to figure out which rule of logic causes the center or operator in the top expression to become an and operator in the bottom expression.  I know that DeMorgan's laws cause the operator to flip, but this doesn't seem to be an example of that.  Thanks for any clarification.


but I'm trying to figure out which rule of logic causes the center "or" operator in the top expression to become an "and" operator in the bottom expression.
\begin{align}
p\not\leftrightarrow q\equiv&(p\land\lnot q)\lor(\lnot p\land q)\\
\equiv&((p\land\lnot q) ∨ ¬p) \land ((p\land\lnot q) \lor q)
\end{align}

In propositional logic, this is called the Distributive Law:
$$\color{orange}{\varphi}\color{red}{\lor}(\color{blue}{\psi}\color{brown}{\land}\color{green}{\chi})\equiv(\color{orange}{\varphi}\color{red}{\lor}\color{blue}{\psi})\color{brown}{\land}(\color{orange}{\varphi}\color{red}{\lor}\color{green}{\chi})$$
Here is how it was applied in the equivalence above:
\begin{align}
p\not\leftrightarrow q\equiv&\color{orange}{(p\land\lnot q)}\color{red}{\lor}(\color{blue}{\lnot p}\color{brown}{\land} \color{green}{q})\tag*{By Definition}\\
\equiv&(\color{orange}{(p\land\lnot q)}\color{red}{\lor} \color{blue}{\lnot p})\color{brown}{\land} (\color{orange}{(p\land\lnot q)}\color{red}{\lor} \color{green}{q})\tag*{Distributive Law}
\end{align}

Thanks, this makes sense.  The use of colors is very helpful to understand how the terms are distributed over one another.

$P\iff Q=(\neg P\wedge \neg Q)\vee (P\wedge Q)$. So, just using $$\neg (A\vee B)=\neg A\wedge \neg B\quad \text{and}\quad \neg (A\wedge B)=\neg A\vee \neg B,$$
gives
\begin{align*}
\neg(P\iff Q)&=\neg(\neg P\wedge \neg Q)\wedge \neg(P\wedge Q)\\
&=(P\vee Q)\wedge (\neg P\vee \neg Q)\\
&=(P\wedge \neg Q)\vee (\neg P\wedge Q).
\end{align*}

Thank you—between Ethan's explanation above and the one you gave, I understand this now.
